# Add users to fire base with a sign up controller

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have entered all of the code below, and I have added all of the proper outlets. When I click to register a new user nothing happens.

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.Email.text!, password: self.Password.text!) { (user, error) in
            if user != nil
            {
                if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                    switch errCode {
                    case .invalidEmail:
                        print("invalid email")
                    case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                        print("in use")
                    default:
                        print("Other error!")
                    }
                        //Register successful
                 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
```

when I click the register button, It just clicks and nothing happens.  I get these messages as well

> The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
>   2018-02-08 16:41:42.646651-0500 Odd Jobs LLC.[15019:754999] [MC]
>   System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   path is
>   /Users/zachwilcox/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/73810829-9867-4481-A947-09DDF164C926/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2018-02-08 16:41:42.652531-0500 Odd Jobs LLC.[15019:754999] [MC]
>   Reading from private effective user settings. 2018-02-08
>   16:41:42.659558-0500 Odd Jobs LLC.[15019:754999] Could not
>   successfully update network info during initialization. 2018-02-08
>   16:41:42.870043-0500 Odd Jobs LLC.[15019:755156] TIC Read Status
>   [1:0x0]: 1:57 2018-02-08 16:41:42.870219-0500 Odd Jobs
>   LLC.[15019:755156] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57 2018-02-08
>   16:41:42.886357-0500 Odd Jobs LLC.[15019:755155] TIC Read Status
>   [2:0x0]: 1:57 2018-02-08 16:41:42.886501-0500 Odd Jobs
>   LLC.[15019:755155] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57 2018-02-08
>   16:41:42.970100-0500 Odd Jobs LLC.[15019:755155] TIC Read Status
>   [4:0x0]: 1:57 2018-02-08 16:41:42.970266-0500 Odd Jobs
>   LLC.[15019:755155] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57

Comment: Are you testing with a certain test password? If so, what is it?

Comment: Also, it appears that your "success segue" is in the AuthError block.

Comment: I don’t think I’m testing with a text password, if I am how do I found out?

Comment: Also, does the segue have to be before or after the block??

Comment: What are the values of self.Email.text! and self.Password.text when the createUser function is called? Your error seems specific to those values.

Comment: I don’t remember setting any values. All of the code that I have up top, is the code in my project. Should I delete those error messages?

Comment: To create a user, you need to provide an email and password to create an account, just like in any account for any system. My question is what values are going into email and password whether you're hard coding them or you're entering them into the Email and Password UITextFields.

Comment: Are they child values? If so do you know what those values would be?

Comment: Your code assumes there are UITextFields or something (you said you added all necessary outlets) that the user is entering an email and password. Your above code is extracting those strings and handing them to firebase's createUser function. If that isn't whats happening, your project is missing the whole login process/UI that you see in any mobile app/website login process.

Comment: All of the code that I have above is all of the code that I have on my lines. Please tell me if there is anything I need to input or delete

Comment: What exactly am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate hot stackoverflow wont let me add a comment because my reputation is too low but

Could you add this to your code and tell us what the error is?

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.Email.text!, password: self.Password.text!) { (user, error) in
        if user != nil
        {
            if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                switch errCode {
                case .invalidEmail:
                    print("invalid email")
                case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                    print("in use")
                default:
                    print("Other error!")
                }
                    //Register successful
             self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        } else {
            // This should be able to tell you what's wrong 
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```

Comment: "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password" this what I receive. I know i seem like im asking for a lot but could you show me how it is supposed to look?

Comment: @ZachWilcox sure I was on the same boat as you are before. But before that can you make sure that your password textfield is connected to your IBOutlet?

Comment: @ZachWilcox also before the Auth.auth() method try print(self.Email.text!) and print(self.Password.text!) to see what is printed

Comment: yes all of the outlets are properly attached. I get this error code.   The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.
2018-02-08 22:27:37.139046-0500 Odd Jobs LLC.[20382:1024973] [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] updateChildValues: at / failed: permission_denied